# Is the warning "Don't edit this post for simple mistakes" ignored

Tags: discussion

I can't remember what exactly but before I had enough points to edit a post myself, when I clicked on edit, I'd get a warning like "Don't suggest simple edits like changing a spelling mistake'. Now that I'm reviewing edits, there seem to be a lot of simple edits, "I'm using C# and...", edited to "I'm using `C#` and...", maybe multiple times in the same edit. Do people just ignore this warning? Should I reject them? It makes the post little more readable, it's acceptable, but it's a minor edit.

Comment: Using code markup for things that aren't code (e.g. language/library names) is incorrect and is actively introducing a mistake - reject.

Comment: @Flexo That was just an example but the gist of it is that there seem to be a lot of minor edits, not necessarily misusing code mark-up.

Comment: As long as there is reputation awarded for approved suggested edits, people will attempt to do the least amount of work necessary to game the system for points. That reviewers time and time again approve downright harmful suggested edits does not help to reinforce the correct behaviour.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I also remember there being a rejection message when you edit less than so many chars, can that be made to be smarter? The edit might have more than 10 (whatever the limit is) chars, but they're all silly edits. Can that rejection be made to recognise these?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy As in your example, some edits are just bolding text, they add up to more than 10 chars, but without a benefit, so the engine just ignores ** edits so they don't count in the char count for example?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy. I edit posts because I enjoy editing and bad grammar sets my teeth on edge. Now I have a high enough rep to edit without bothering reviewers, I do it *more*, not less. It has never had anything to do with looking for points.

Comment: @TRiG: if I implied that all people are doing it because of what I describe, I certainly did not mean to. Of course there are people who do thing out of goodwill for the community and that is much appreciated. However, more often than not I see numerous users who seem to view reputation as a means to itself, rather than what is intended to achieve.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks, I started rejecting those sort of edits and noticed other reviewers reject them as well. When you approve you don't see what other reviewers have voted for, but when you reject you get the "reject reason" popup which shows the reason why the others have rejected.